I am trying to add a new event i to the existing events in a date or new events to a date using n Jquery Fullcalendar control
I am trying to add a new event to the jquery calendar control. I can see existing event in each date but I cannot add a new event . I am looking for a help to add new event to the calendar control. Here is the code in mvc. I am trying to call a model called _calendarEvent.cshtml from the main page CalendarEntry.cshtml.  But the model view  _calendarEvent is called only from the row where there is no event on the calendar other wise it will not be called any where any event is being recorded.
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script> 

<div>
     <hr style="margin-top:unset" />
         <div style="color: black;" id="calendar"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function getEvents() {
            var depotNo = 1;
            var departmentId = 1;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Attendance/GetEvents',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    depotNo: depotNo,
                    departmentId: departmentId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        defaultView: 'month',
                        editable: true,
                        events: data,
                        eventAfterAllRender: function () {
                            // Ensure the button is added for all days after all events are rendered
                            $('#calendar').find('.fc-day, .fc-event-container').each(function () {
                                var date = $(this).data('date');
                                if (date) { // Only proceed if date is available
                                    var button = $('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Add/Edit Event</button>');
                                    button.on('click', function () {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: '/Attendance/LoadEventEntryPartial',
                                            type: 'GET',
                                            data: { date: date },
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                $('#modalContent').html(data); // Load the partial view content into the modal body
                                                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                            },
                                            error: function () {
                                                alert('Error loading event entry form.');
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });

                                    // Avoid adding the button multiple times
                                    if (!$(this).find('button').length) {
                                        $(this).append(button);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
  

The existing event is called from the action method
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetEvents(int depotNo , int departmentId)
        {
            

            int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(currentYear, 12, 31);

            var attendancelog = _db.goAttendancelog.Where(a => !a.IsDeleted 
                                                    && a.DepotNo == depotNo
                                                    && a.DepartmentID == departmentId
                                                    && a.AttendanceDate >= startDate 
                                                    && a.AttendanceDate <= endDate 
                                                    && (a.HolidayHrs > 0 || a.DayOffHrs > 0 || a.UnPaidHrs > 0 || a.PaidHrs > 0)).Select(c => new AttendanceOverViewModel
            {
                EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID,
                EmployeeName = c.EmployeeModel.EmployeeName,
                AttendanceDate = c.AttendanceDate,                 
                HolidayHrs= c.HolidayHrs,
                DayOffHrs = c.DayOffHrs,
                UnPaidHrs= c.UnPaidHrs,
                PaidHrs = c.PaidHrs,                
            });

            var events = attendancelog.Select(a => new
            {
                title = a.HolidayHrs > 0 ? $"{a.EmployeeName} - Holiday" : a.DayOffHrs > 0 ? $"{a.EmployeeName} - Day Off" : a.UnPaidHrs > 0 ? $"{a.EmployeeName} - Unpaid Leave" : $"{a.EmployeeName} - Paid Leave",
                start = a.AttendanceDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                end = a.AttendanceDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            }).ToList();

            // Return the events as JSON
            return Json(events);
        }

Here is the model page _calendarEvent.cshtml is called when I click the button from the calendar page.
public IActionResult LoadEventEntryPartial(string date)
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedDate = date;
            var model = new CalendarEventViewModel();


            return PartialView("~/Views/Attendance/_calendarEvent.cshtml", model);
        }

